# Can you check if https is enabled on frontend from admin

Tags: admin, front-end, https

Writing a plugin. I would like to remove an option in admin interface if the frontend is not served over https. Is there a reliable way to check frontend schema?

Comment: You have a browser open (coz admin interface is open). Why not check directly from browser with https: //yoursite/ ?

Comment: is `is_ssl` not sufficient? but not sure what you mean by frontend when admin is really more backend.

Comment: The website can be served from both HTTP and HTTPS at the same time, depending on the website (and server) configuration. If you want to ensure that HTTPS is used, you can add rules in .htaccess (if using Apache) to force HTTPS connection.

Comment: @majick Some hosters provide "SSL proxy", which can be used for wp-admin. If you do, `is_ssl` will be true when in the admin (and checking the settings), but not in the frontend

Comment: Looks like the question was misunderstood. By "frontend", I mean the visitor-facing part of the site, and by "admin" I mean the wp-admin. My code executes in the admin part, but I want to know if the frontend part is being served over https.

Comment: @IvanČurdinjaković Without actually checking (eg via Guzzle), does it not suffice to simply check `get_option( 'home' )` (aka the URL that is set in settings)?

Comment: question is weird. sounds like you have decided on the solution before fully understanding the problem. probably worth editing the question and add details about what exactly that option supposed to do/deny